# Rails 3 does not show jQuery Date Picker

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, datetime, formtastic

I followed a [Railscast by RyanB](http://railscasts.com/episodes/213-calendars) to add jQuery date_picker to a form and and got stuck for a couple days now. According to the instruction, there are only three changes:

1. Change application.html.erb to include jQuery and jQuery-ui (see my application.html.erb below)
2. Change date_select field to text to accommodate jQuery. I made the change in my _form.html.erb:

   <%= f.text_field :born_in %>
3. Add to application.js the following statement:

   ```
   $(function() {
   $("#spec_born_in").datepicker();
     });
   ```

The tricky problem for me is that I am using FullCalendar (a JavaScript plugin). For some reason, if I add anything to applicaiton.js, FullCalendar won't show up. Therefore, I need to put the function definition to a file I called application_jquery_helper.js, and load it after loading FullCalendar's js files.

I have done all these but in my form, the text field is just a text field, and jQuery datepicker would not show up.

I wonder what I did incorrectly that prevented jQuery datepicker from showing up. The only reason I can think of is the order in which I included js files in my application.html.erb, but I don't know how to fix it.

Below is my rather big  in application.html.erb:

```
  <head>
<%= csrf_meta_tag %>
<%= render 'layouts/stylesheets'%>
<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
<!-- <%=stylesheet_link_tag'blueprint/screen',:media=>'screen'%> 
<%=stylesheet_link_tag'blueprint/print',:media=>'print'%> -->
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'formtastic', 'formtastic_changes', :cache => "base" %>

<%= stylesheet_link_tag "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css", "application" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js",
           "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/jquery-ui.min.js", "application" %>

<%= stylesheet_link_tag "fullcalendar.css" %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application.css" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "jquery.js" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "jquery.rest.js" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "rails.js" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application.js" %>
   <!-- these are needed for the calendar. -->
 <%= javascript_include_tag "jquery-ui-1.8.11.custom.min.js" %>
 <%= javascript_include_tag "fullcalendar.js" %>
 <%= javascript_include_tag "calendar.js" %>
 <%= javascript_include_tag "application_jquery_helper.js" %>
```

Comments or suggestions are very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are trying to access an element when the DOM isn't fully loaded.

To correct this issue:

```
$(document).ready(function(ev) {
  $("#spec_born_in").datepicker();
});
```

You can also look at [jQuery's `.live()` functionality](http://api.jquery.com/live/) if you need "future" support.

Comment: Thanks Adam. In my case, it was the conflict between prototype and jQuery that causes the issue.

Comment: Ahhh, yeah, sometimes they don't play nicely.